# Input Accessory View doesn't have a height until it is active

Tags: swift, inputaccessoryview

So I have an inputAccessoryView that doesn't have a height until it is initialised. So until you click on it and begin to type, the text cells are behind the the accessoryView and they cannot be seen, it's only until it becomes active and I begin typing that I can scroll all the way down. Now I know I can change the inset sizes and that will fix it but when I start typing again I now have more scrolling space that I don't want. Super frustrating.

Code below:

```
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        collectionView?.register(ChatMessageCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
        collectionView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: 8, left: 0, bottom:8, right: 0)
        collectionView?.backgroundColor = .moonNavy
        collectionView?.alwaysBounceVertical = true
        collectionView?.keyboardDismissMode = .interactive
        
        loadCurrentUserObject()
        setupKeyboardObserve()
    }



  override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
    var _inputAccessoryView: UIView!
    let textView = UITextView()

    override var inputAccessoryView: UIView? {

        if ( _inputAccessoryView == nil ){

            _inputAccessoryView = CustomView()
            _inputAccessoryView.backgroundColor = UIColor.moonNavy

            //let textView = UITextView()
            textView.font = UIFont(name: "Arial Rounded MT Bold", size: 16)
            textView.text = "Send a message..."
            textView.textColor = .lightGray
            
            textView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
            textView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
            //_inputAccessoryView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 90).isActive = true
            //textView.borderStyle = .roundedRect
            
            
            let uploadImageView = UIImageView()
            uploadImageView.image = UIImage(named: "gallery-icon")
            uploadImageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            let tap = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleUploadTap))
            uploadImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tap)
            uploadImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
            _inputAccessoryView.addSubview(uploadImageView)
            

            _inputAccessoryView.addSubview(textView)
            //uploadImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true
            uploadImageView.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            uploadImageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            uploadImageView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
            //uploadImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _inputAccessoryView.topAnchor).isActive = true

            
            _inputAccessoryView.addSubview(sendButton)
            sendButton.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: _inputAccessoryView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            sendButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: textView.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
            sendButton.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uploadImageView.rightAnchor).isActive = true
            sendButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant:60).isActive = true
            uploadImageView.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: sendButton.leftAnchor).isActive = true


            _inputAccessoryView.autoresizingMask = .flexibleHeight
            
            textView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

            textView.leadingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: _inputAccessoryView.leadingAnchor,
                constant: 10
            ).isActive = true

            textView.trailingAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: uploadImageView.leadingAnchor,
                constant: -10
            ).isActive = true

            textView.topAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: _inputAccessoryView.topAnchor,
                constant: 10
            ).isActive = true

            
            // this is the important part :
            textView.bottomAnchor.constraint(
                equalTo: _inputAccessoryView.layoutMarginsGuide.bottomAnchor,
                constant: -10
            ).isActive = true
            textView.delegate = self
            textView.isScrollEnabled = false
            
            textViewDidChange(textView)
        }

        return _inputAccessoryView
    }






class CustomView: UIView {
    override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
        return CGSize.zero
    }
}
```

Comment: 1) Why isn't all of the code to setup the content of `CustomView` inside the implementation of the `CustomView` class? 2) `CustomView` should extend `UIInputView`, not `UIView`. 3) Why did you set the `intrinsicContentSize` to `CGSize.zero` if you don't want the default size to be zero?

Comment: @HangarRash Yeah seems like a few things i need to fix here  Could I just change the CGSize.zero to something else?

Comment: If you want the input view to have a different intrinsic size then yes, change the `CGSize.zero` to a more appropriate value.

Comment: @HangarRash The reason I did the CGSize.zero was to autosize the value once a user starts typing, that works fine, what I essentially want is a minimum height when the user isn't typing so the cells are actually above the inputAccessoryView and not behind it.